# Улучшить время работы алгоритма на Питоне

Tags: python

Нужно улучшить алгоритм так чтобы он работал за линейное время:

```
a,p=map(int,input().split()) 
result=0 
for i in range(p-a+1): 
   result+=(a+i)^(a-1+i) 
print(result)
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что должен делать этот алгоритм?

Comment: Он и работает за линейное время O(p-a). Значит, улучшать этот загадочный алгоритм не требуется.

Comment: Если бы у вас результат накапливался через XOR, а не обычное сложение, то алгоритм можно было бы "оптимизировать", оставив первое и последнее слагаемые, так как цикл стал бы ненужным (все промежуточные значения сбросились бы в 0): `(a ^ (a - 1)) ^ ((a + 1) ^ a) ^ ((a +2) ^ (a + 1))...((a + p - a - 1) ^ (a - 1 + p - a - 1)) ^ ((a + p - a) ^ (a - 1 + p - a))` = `(a - 1) ^ p`

Answer (score 1):

*f(a, b)* - функция, которую считаем. Заметим что она "аддитивная":
*f(a, b) = f(1, b) - f(1, a - 1)*. Достаточно научиться вычислять *g(a) = f(1, a)*.

Таблица значений *n ^ (n - 1)*:

> ```
>  n  n^(n - 1)
>  1      1      = 1
>  2      3      = 1 + 2
>  3      1      = 1
>  4      7      = 1 + 2 + 4
>  5      1      = 1
>  6      3      = 1 + 2
>  7      1      = 1
>  8     15      = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8
>  9      1      = 1
> 10      3      = 1 + 2
> 11      1      = 1
> 12      7      = 1 + 2 + 4
> 13      1      = 1
> 14      3      = 1 + 2
> 15      1      = 1
> 16     31      = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16
> ```

Чему равно *g(11)*? В него входят первые одиннадцать строк таблицы. В том числе одиннадцать единиц, пять (*11 // 2*) двоек, две (*11 // 4*) четвёрки и одна (*11 // 8*) восьмёрка:

```
def g(a):
    p2 = 1  # очередная степень двойки
    s = 0
    while p2 <= a:
        s += p2 * (a // p2)
        p2 *= 2  # следующая степень двойки
    return s
```

То же самое можно записать в виде битовых операций:

```
def g(a):
    bit = 1
    s = 0
    while a > 0:
        s += a
        a &= ~bit
        bit <<= 1
    return s
```

Целиком программа выглядит так:

```
def g(a):
    bit = 1
    s = 0
    while a > 0:
        s += a
        a &= ~bit
        bit <<= 1
    return s


def f(a, b):
    return g(b) - g(a - 1)


print(f(*map(int, input().split())))
```

Сложность: *O(log<sup>2</sup>b)*.

> ```
> $ time echo 1 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000 | python xor-sum.py
> 99448632303590039339268692770816
>
> real  0m0.029s
> user  0m0.024s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```